# regarding hbase running on hadoop in distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase, distributed-computing

Hadoop version=2.4.1
hbase version=0.98.6

i have hadoop up and running prefectly fine on below conf:
107.108.86.119-hadoop namenode,SecondaryNameNode
107.109.155.100-datanode1
107.109.155.102-datanode2

now i install hbase as below conf:-
107.108.86.114:-hmaster,HQuorumPeer
107.109.155.100-regionserver1
107.109.155.102-regionserver2

when i do jps following process are running:
107.109.155.102:-hregionserver,datanode
107.109.155.100:-hregionserver,datanode
107.108.86.119:-NameNode,secondaryNameNode
107.108.86.114:-hmaster

but on doing status on hbase shell is showing "0 servers, 0 dead, NaN average load"
 on entering cmd on hbase shell showing ERROR: java.io.IOException: Table Namespace Manager not ready yet, try again later

logs on regionserver showing: 
regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty to master=localhost,60000,1415007213689 with port=60020, startcode=1415007215055
regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up

my hbase-site.xml-

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>107.108.86.114:60000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://push-mcd2:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
 </property>
<property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>107.108.86.114</value>
</property>
```

while /etc/hosts of hmaster is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost arpita-ubuntu 
127.0.1.1       arpita-ubuntu
107.109.155.100 push-ws1
107.109.155.102 push-ws2 
107.108.86.114  push-mcd1 
107.108.86.119  push-mcd2
```

WHILE slaves file are also almost similiar to above one.

conf/hbase-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22 export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

so what change i make so hbase will run on above cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your regionserver log mentions that it is looking for HBase Master on localhost?
Form information above you have setup Master on a node different for either regionservers, please check your config is correct on each node.

> logs on regionserver showing: regionserver.HRegionServer:
>   reportForDuty to **master=localhost**,60000,1415007213689 with port=60020,
>   startcode=1415007215055 regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling
>   master we are up

Also in /etc/hosts on each node please update first two lines from

```
127.0.0.1   localhost arpita-ubuntu 
127.0.1.1       arpita-ubuntu
```

to

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
<Actual_IP_Address_for_Host>   arpita-ubuntu
```

This is necessary if you don't have automatic dns name resolution in place.

Also please use IP instead of localhost in all config settings.

If you still face issues, check if the respective ports are open or not.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i try  above modification, but it didnt work. the thing i notice is on master machine itself it listening to 60000 port on "telnet localhost 60000" but on giving machine ip ("telnet 107.108.86.114 60000 ") it cant connect. can u help ?

Comment: Is your IP address assigned by a dhcp service or you have manually configured it through /etc/hosts, If you have done it manually can you share you /etc/hosts entry for HBase Master and Regionservers m/c

Comment: Your cluster is set up on ubuntu?

Comment: sry for late response. yes my cluster is on ubuntu.i have assign ip through /etc/hosts. u can see hosts file for master and slave in above edit

Comment: Can you change line in hosts file "127.0.0.1 localhost arpita-ubuntu" to "127.0.0.1   localhost" and remove the next line "127.0.1.1 arpita-ubuntu", Also are you able to ssh your hmaster via IP from your regionservers?

Comment: yes i able to ssh from slave machine to master. the error the region server is giving now is   "xn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authentic  using SASL"

Comment: In hbase-site.xml on regionservers have you set hbase.master property as localhost? Can you change that to IP address?

Comment: When you do jps do you see Zookeeper?